# Disparar evento para mudar imagem do slider ao clicar nas setas direcionais do teclado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navegação

Estou utilizando um slider do jQuery, porém gostaria de melhorá-lo no quesito **Acessibilidade**.

Gostaria que as setas do teclado, a da esquerda <kbd>←</kbd> e da direita <kbd>→</kbd>, navegassem meu slider de forma similar ao clique nas flechas de navegação. Porém eu também gostaria que ao pressionar as teclas direcionais, a imagem do slide mudasse obedecendo a direção em qual foi teclada(animação frequentemente encontrada em aplicações de galeria para mobile).

Logo se o usuário pressionar <kbd>→</kbd>, desejo que a imagem suma para a esquerda, e caso pressionar <kbd>←</kbd> desejo que a imagem suma para a direita.

```js
/*! http://responsiveslides.com v1.54 by @viljamis */
(function (c, I, B) {
  c.fn.responsiveSlides = function (l) {
    var a = c.extend({
      auto: !0,
      speed: 500,
      timeout: 4000,
      pager: !1,
      nav: !1,
      random: !1,
      pause: !1,
      pauseControls: !0,
      prevText: 'Previous',
      nextText: 'Next',
      maxwidth: '',
      navContainer: '',
      manualControls: '',
      namespace: 'rslides',
      before: c.noop,
      after: c.noop
    }, l);
    return this.each(function () {
      B++;
      var f = c(this),
      s,
      r,
      t,
      m,
      p,
      q,
      n = 0,
      e = f.children(),
      C = e.size(),
      h = parseFloat(a.speed),
      D = parseFloat(a.timeout),
      u = parseFloat(a.maxwidth),
      g = a.namespace,
      d = g + B,
      E = g + '_nav ' + d + '_nav',
      v = g + '_here',
      j = d + '_on',
      w = d + '_s',
      k = c('<ul class=\'' + g + '_tabs ' + d + '_tabs\' />'),
      x = {
        'float': 'left',
        position: 'relative',
        opacity: 1,
        zIndex: 2
      },
      y = {
        'float': 'none',
        position: 'absolute',
        opacity: 0,
        zIndex: 1
      },
      F = function () {
        var b = (document.body || document.documentElement).style,
        a = 'transition';
        if ('string' === typeof b[a]) return !0;
        s = [
          'Moz',
          'Webkit',
          'Khtml',
          'O',
          'ms'
        ];
        var a = a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.substr(1),
        c;
        for (c = 0; c < s.length; c++) if ('string' === typeof b[s[c] + a]) return !0;
        return !1
      }(),
      z = function (b) {
        a.before(b);
        F ? (e.removeClass(j).css(y).eq(b).addClass(j).css(x), n = b, setTimeout(function () {
          a.after(b)
        }, h))  : e.stop().fadeOut(h, function () {
          c(this).removeClass(j).css(y).css('opacity', 1)
        }).eq(b).fadeIn(h, function () {
          c(this).addClass(j).css(x);
          a.after(b);
          n = b
        })
      };
      a.random && (e.sort(function () {
        return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5
      }), f.empty().append(e));
      e.each(function (a) {
        this.id = w + a
      });
      f.addClass(g + ' ' + d);
      l && l.maxwidth && f.css('max-width', u);
      e.hide().css(y).eq(0).addClass(j).css(x).show();
      F && e.show().css({
        '-webkit-transition': 'opacity ' + h + 'ms ease-in-out',
        '-moz-transition': 'opacity ' +
        h + 'ms ease-in-out',
        '-o-transition': 'opacity ' + h + 'ms ease-in-out',
        transition: 'opacity ' + h + 'ms ease-in-out'
      });
      if (1 < e.size()) {
        if (D < h + 100) return;
        if (a.pager && !a.manualControls) {
          var A = [
          ];
          e.each(function (a) {
            a += 1;
            A += '<li><a href=\'#\' class=\'' + w + a + '\'>' + a + '</a></li>'
          });
          k.append(A);
          l.navContainer ? c(a.navContainer).append(k)  : f.after(k)
        }
        a.manualControls && (k = c(a.manualControls), k.addClass(g + '_tabs ' + d + '_tabs'));
        (a.pager || a.manualControls) && k.find('li').each(function (a) {
          c(this).addClass(w + (a + 1))
        });
        if (a.pager || a.manualControls) q =
        k.find('a'),
        r = function (a) {
          q.closest('li').removeClass(v).eq(a).addClass(v)
        };
        a.auto && (t = function () {
          p = setInterval(function () {
            e.stop(!0, !0);
            var b = n + 1 < C ? n + 1 : 0;
            (a.pager || a.manualControls) && r(b);
            z(b)
          }, D)
        }, t());
        m = function () {
          a.auto && (clearInterval(p), t())
        };
        a.pause && f.hover(function () {
          clearInterval(p)
        }, function () {
          m()
        });
        if (a.pager || a.manualControls) q.bind('click', function (b) {
          b.preventDefault();
          a.pauseControls || m();
          b = q.index(this);
          n === b || c('.' + j).queue('fx').length || (r(b), z(b))
        }).eq(0).closest('li').addClass(v),
        a.pauseControls && q.hover(function () {
          clearInterval(p)
        }, function () {
          m()
        });
        if (a.nav) {
          g = '<a href=\'#\' class=\'' + E + ' prev\'>' + a.prevText + '</a><a href=\'#\' class=\'' + E + ' next\'>' + a.nextText + '</a>';
          l.navContainer ? c(a.navContainer).append(g)  : f.after(g);
          var d = c('.' + d + '_nav'),
          G = d.filter('.prev');
          d.bind('click', function (b) {
            b.preventDefault();
            b = c('.' + j);
            if (!b.queue('fx').length) {
              var d = e.index(b);
              b = d - 1;
              d = d + 1 < C ? n + 1 : 0;
              z(c(this) [0] === G[0] ? b : d);
              if (a.pager || a.manualControls) r(c(this) [0] === G[0] ? b : d);
              a.pauseControls || m()
            }
          });
          a.pauseControls && d.hover(function () {
            clearInterval(p)
          }, function () {
            m()
          })
        }
      }
      if ('undefined' === typeof document.body.style.maxWidth && l.maxwidth) {
        var H = function () {
          f.css('width', '100%');
          f.width() > u && f.css('width', u)
        };
        H();
        c(I).bind('resize', function () {
          H()
        })
      }
    })
  }
}) (jQuery, this, 0);

    $(function () {
      // Slideshow 4
      $("#slider4").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 0,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
      });

    });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Callback example */


.callbacks_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height:520px; background:#C39
  }

.callbacks {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.callbacks_nav {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  top: 52%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 3;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 61px;
  width: 38px;
  background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/lWEau8H.gif") no-repeat left top;
  margin-top: -45px;
  }

.callbacks_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
  }

.callbacks_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0;
  }


/*! BOX DO SLIDE */

.rslides {width:100%; position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); text-align:center;}

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li img {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height:90%;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font: 24px/50px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
  .callbacks_nav {
    top: 47%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="callbacks_container">
      <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
        <li><img src="http://prodigital.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Relogio-antigo-closeup.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.robsonpiresxerife.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/relogio-111.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://relogiolandia.com/files/artigos/relogio-bolso.jpg" alt=""></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Explicação:

Bom sua solução pode ser simplesmente resolvida utilizando o evento `keyup` diretamente aplicado no corpo do seu documento(body) e checando se a tecla que o usuário clicou foi <kbd>←</kbd>[keyCode: 37] ou <kbd>→</kbd>[keyCode: 39] deste jeito, a seguir:

## Código:

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){
  const KEY_LEFT  = 37;
  const KEY_RIGHT = 39;
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case KEY_LEFT  : {
      $('.next').click(); //sendo o "inverso" como você disse
      break;
    }
    case KEY_RIGHT : {
      $('.prev').click(); //sendo o "inverso" como você disse
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

## Animação:

Porém pelo visto você quer que a imagem "vá para esquerda" ou "vá para direita" o que dá a entender que você quer que o usuário perceba que a imagem tendeu a esta direção, por isso você precisaria de uma animação (parecida com a utilizada por padrão na galeria de fotos de um smartphone), aí então você pode utilizar o .animate() do jQuery:

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){
    const KEY_LEFT  = 37;
    const KEY_RIGHT = 39;
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case KEY_LEFT  : {
            animationSpeed = 100; //mude a velocidade aqui
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.next').click(); //passa para a próxima imagem
            }, animationSpeed);
            $('.callbacks_container li img').addClass('relativepos'); //possibilita a img a se mover com o left
            $('.callbacks_container li img').animate({
              left: "-100%"
              }, animationSpeed, function() {
                $('.callbacks_container li img').attr('style', 'left: 100%;'); //força a imagem a surgir da direita
                $('.callbacks_container li img').animate({
                    left: "0%"
                  }, animationSpeed);                          
            });
            break;
        }
        case KEY_RIGHT : {
            animationSpeed = 100; //mude a velocidade aqui
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.prev').click(); //vai para a imagem anterior
            }, animationSpeed);
            $('.callbacks_container li img').addClass('relativepos'); //possibilita a imagem a mover-se com o left
            $('.callbacks_container li img').animate({
              left: "100%"
              }, animationSpeed, function() {
                $('.callbacks_container li img').attr('style', 'left: -100%;'); //força a imagem a surgir da esquerda
                $('.callbacks_container li img').animate({
                    left: "0%"
                  }, animationSpeed);
            });
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

## Exemplo:

```js
$('body').keyup(function(e){
    const KEY_LEFT  = 37;
    const KEY_RIGHT = 39;
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case KEY_LEFT  : {
            animationSpeed = 100; //mude a velocidade aqui
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.next').click(); //passa para a próxima imagem
            }, animationSpeed);
            $('.callbacks_container li img').addClass('relativepos'); //possibilita a img a se mover com o left
            $('.callbacks_container li img').animate({
              left: "-100%"
              }, animationSpeed, function() {
                $('.callbacks_container li img').attr('style', 'left: 100%;'); //força a imagem a surgir da direita
                $('.callbacks_container li img').animate({
                    left: "0%"
                  }, animationSpeed);                          
            });
            break;
        }
        case KEY_RIGHT : {
            animationSpeed = 100; //mude a velocidade aqui
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.prev').click(); //vai para a imagem anterior
            }, animationSpeed);
            $('.callbacks_container li img').addClass('relativepos'); //possibilita a imagem a mover-se com o left
            $('.callbacks_container li img').animate({
              left: "100%"
              }, animationSpeed, function() {
                $('.callbacks_container li img').attr('style', 'left: -100%;'); //força a imagem a surgir da esquerda
                $('.callbacks_container li img').animate({
                    left: "0%"
                  }, animationSpeed);
            });
            break;
        }
    }
});


(function ($, window, i) {
  $.fn.responsiveSlides = function (options) {

    // Default settings
    var settings = $.extend({
      "auto": true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
      "speed": 500,             // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
      "timeout": 4000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
      "pager": false,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
      "nav": false,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
      "random": false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
      "pause": false,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
      "pauseControls": true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
      "prevText": "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
      "nextText": "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
      "maxwidth": "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
      "navContainer": "",       // Selector: Where auto generated controls should be appended to, default is after the <ul>
      "manualControls": "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
      "namespace": "rslides",   // String: change the default namespace used
      "before": $.noop,         // Function: Before callback
      "after": $.noop           // Function: After callback
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {

      // Index for namespacing
      i++;

      var $this = $(this),

        // Local variables
        vendor,
        selectTab,
        startCycle,
        restartCycle,
        rotate,
        $tabs,

        // Helpers
        index = 0,
        $slide = $this.children(),
        length = $slide.size(),
        fadeTime = parseFloat(settings.speed),
        waitTime = parseFloat(settings.timeout),
        maxw = parseFloat(settings.maxwidth),

        // Namespacing
        namespace = settings.namespace,
        namespaceIdx = namespace + i,

        // Classes
        navClass = namespace + "_nav " + namespaceIdx + "_nav",
        activeClass = namespace + "_here",
        visibleClass = namespaceIdx + "_on",
        slideClassPrefix = namespaceIdx + "_s",

        // Pager
        $pager = $("<ul class='" + namespace + "_tabs " + namespaceIdx + "_tabs' />"),

        // Styles for visible and hidden slides
        visible = {"float": "left", "position": "relative", "opacity": 1, "zIndex": 2},
        hidden = {"float": "none", "position": "absolute", "opacity": 0, "zIndex": 1},

        // Detect transition support
        supportsTransitions = (function () {
          var docBody = document.body || document.documentElement;
          var styles = docBody.style;
          var prop = "transition";
          if (typeof styles[prop] === "string") {
            return true;
          }
          // Tests for vendor specific prop
          vendor = ["Moz", "Webkit", "Khtml", "O", "ms"];
          prop = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.substr(1);
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < vendor.length; i++) {
            if (typeof styles[vendor[i] + prop] === "string") {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        })(),

        // Fading animation
        slideTo = function (idx) {
          settings.before(idx);
          // If CSS3 transitions are supported
          if (supportsTransitions) {
            $slide
              .removeClass(visibleClass)
              .css(hidden)
              .eq(idx)
              .addClass(visibleClass)
              .css(visible);
            index = idx;
            setTimeout(function () {
              settings.after(idx);
            }, fadeTime);
          // If not, use jQuery fallback
          } else {
            $slide
              .stop()
              .fadeOut(fadeTime, function () {
                $(this)
                  .removeClass(visibleClass)
                  .css(hidden)
                  .css("opacity", 1);
              })
              .eq(idx)
              .fadeIn(fadeTime, function () {
                $(this)
                  .addClass(visibleClass)
                  .css(visible);
                settings.after(idx);
                index = idx;
              });
          }
        };

      // Random order
      if (settings.random) {
        $slide.sort(function () {
          return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
        });
        $this
          .empty()
          .append($slide);
      }

      // Add ID's to each slide
      $slide.each(function (i) {
        this.id = slideClassPrefix + i;
      });

      // Add max-width and classes
      $this.addClass(namespace + " " + namespaceIdx);
      if (options && options.maxwidth) {
        $this.css("max-width", maxw);
      }

      // Hide all slides, then show first one
      $slide
        .hide()
        .css(hidden)
        .eq(0)
        .addClass(visibleClass)
        .css(visible)
        .show();

      // CSS transitions
      if (supportsTransitions) {
        $slide
          .show()
          .css({
            // -ms prefix isn't needed as IE10 uses prefix free version
            "-webkit-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "-moz-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "-o-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out",
            "transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-in-out"
          });
      }

      // Only run if there's more than one slide
      if ($slide.size() > 1) {

        // Make sure the timeout is at least 100ms longer than the fade
        if (waitTime < fadeTime + 100) {
          return;
        }

        // Pager
        if (settings.pager && !settings.manualControls) {
          var tabMarkup = [];
          $slide.each(function (i) {
            var n = i + 1;
            tabMarkup +=
              "<li>" +
              "<a href='#' class='" + slideClassPrefix + n + "'>" + n + "</a>" +
              "</li>";
          });
          $pager.append(tabMarkup);

          // Inject pager
          if (options.navContainer) {
            $(settings.navContainer).append($pager);
          } else {
            $this.after($pager);
          }
        }

        // Manual pager controls
        if (settings.manualControls) {
          $pager = $(settings.manualControls);
          $pager.addClass(namespace + "_tabs " + namespaceIdx + "_tabs");
        }

        // Add pager slide class prefixes
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $pager.find('li').each(function (i) {
            $(this).addClass(slideClassPrefix + (i + 1));
          });
        }

        // If we have a pager, we need to set up the selectTab function
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $tabs = $pager.find('a');

          // Select pager item
          selectTab = function (idx) {
            $tabs
              .closest("li")
              .removeClass(activeClass)
              .eq(idx)
              .addClass(activeClass);
          };
        }

        // Auto cycle
        if (settings.auto) {

          startCycle = function () {
            rotate = setInterval(function () {

              // Clear the event queue
              $slide.stop(true, true);

              var idx = index + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;

              // Remove active state and set new if pager is set
              if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
                selectTab(idx);
              }

              slideTo(idx);
            }, waitTime);
          };

          // Init cycle
          startCycle();
        }

        // Restarting cycle
        restartCycle = function () {
          if (settings.auto) {
            // Stop
            clearInterval(rotate);
            // Restart
            startCycle();
          }
        };

        // Pause on hover
        if (settings.pause) {
          $this.hover(function () {
            clearInterval(rotate);
          }, function () {
            restartCycle();
          });
        }

        // Pager click event handler
        if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
          $tabs.bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (!settings.pauseControls) {
              restartCycle();
            }

            // Get index of clicked tab
            var idx = $tabs.index(this);

            // Break if element is already active or currently animated
            if (index === idx || $("." + visibleClass).queue('fx').length) {
              return;
            }

            // Remove active state from old tab and set new one
            selectTab(idx);

            // Do the animation
            slideTo(idx);
          })
            .eq(0)
            .closest("li")
            .addClass(activeClass);

          // Pause when hovering pager
          if (settings.pauseControls) {
            $tabs.hover(function () {
              clearInterval(rotate);
            }, function () {
              restartCycle();
            });
          }
        }

        // Navigation
        if (settings.nav) {
          var navMarkup =
            "<a href='#' class='" + navClass + " prev'>" + settings.prevText + "</a>" +
            "<a href='#' class='" + navClass + " next'>" + settings.nextText + "</a>";

          // Inject navigation
          if (options.navContainer) {
            $(settings.navContainer).append(navMarkup);
          } else {
            $this.after(navMarkup);
          }

          var $trigger = $("." + namespaceIdx + "_nav"),
            $prev = $trigger.filter(".prev");

          // Click event handler
          $trigger.bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $visibleClass = $("." + visibleClass);

            // Prevent clicking if currently animated
            if ($visibleClass.queue('fx').length) {
              return;
            }

            //  Adds active class during slide animation
            //  $(this)
            //    .addClass(namespace + "_active")
            //    .delay(fadeTime)
            //    .queue(function (next) {
            //      $(this).removeClass(namespace + "_active");
            //      next();
            //  });

            // Determine where to slide
            var idx = $slide.index($visibleClass),
              prevIdx = idx - 1,
              nextIdx = idx + 1 < length ? index + 1 : 0;

            // Go to slide
            slideTo($(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
            if (settings.pager || settings.manualControls) {
              selectTab($(this)[0] === $prev[0] ? prevIdx : nextIdx);
            }

            if (!settings.pauseControls) {
              restartCycle();
            }
          });

          // Pause when hovering navigation
          if (settings.pauseControls) {
            $trigger.hover(function () {
              clearInterval(rotate);
            }, function () {
              restartCycle();
            });
          }
        }

      }

      // Max-width fallback
      if (typeof document.body.style.maxWidth === "undefined" && options.maxwidth) {
        var widthSupport = function () {
          $this.css("width", "100%");
          if ($this.width() > maxw) {
            $this.css("width", maxw);
          }
        };

        // Init fallback
        widthSupport();
        $(window).bind("resize", function () {
          widthSupport();
        });
      }

    });

  };
})(jQuery, this, 0);




    // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
    $(function () {
      // Slideshow 4
      $("#slider4").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 0,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function () {
          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
      });

    });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.relativepos {
  position: relative !important;
}









/* Callback example */


.callbacks_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; height:520px; background:#C39
  }

.callbacks {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }





.callbacks_nav {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  top: 52%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 3;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 61px;
  width: 38px;
  background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/lWEau8H.gif") no-repeat left top;
  margin-top: -45px;
  }

.callbacks_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
  }

.callbacks_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0;
  }


/*! BOX DO SLIDE */

.rslides {width:100%; position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); text-align:center;}

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }



.rslides li img {
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height:90%;
  }


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font: 24px/50px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
  .callbacks_nav {
    top: 47%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="callbacks_container">
      <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">
        <li><img src="http://prodigital.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Relogio-antigo-closeup.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.robsonpiresxerife.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/relogio-111.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="http://relogiolandia.com/files/artigos/relogio-bolso.jpg" alt=""></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

## Observações:

Você tem que adicionar a classe `relativepos` no seu CSS que eu criei para que a imagem se mova ao alterar o atributo `left`:

```
.relativepos {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: o que você falo até funciono, as imagens vão pro lado, so que elas apenas vão pro lado, porque a imagem fica se repetindo, e a intenção é passar pro lado e mostrar a próxima imagem da lista, e não a mesma. E sobre o fato de passar pro "lado" não precisa levar ao pé da letra, quando eu disse passar pro lado eu apenas me referia a mudar a imagem pra próxima seja ela a anterior ou a proxima. Olha no exemplo "http://jsfiddle.net/veloosooo/ccr25peL/3/". Se clicar nas setas as imagens mudam, agora se usar as setas do teclado as imagens vão pro lado, só que repete a mesma.

Comment: Certo, realmente estava com problemas, eu corrigi e editei esta resposta, confira @ivanveloso

Comment: Agora sim. Ficou perfeito. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Amigo uma forma legal de fazer é usar o plugin cycle e adicionar o códio KEY.
assim:

/    ATIVA AS TECLAS DO TECLADO PARA MOVIMENTAR O SLIDE

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){
    const KEY_LEFT  = 37;
    const KEY_RIGHT = 39;
    switch(e.keyCode){
    case KEY_LEFT  : {
        $('.prev').click(); 
    break;
}

    case KEY_RIGHT : {
        $('.next').click(); 
    break;
        }
    }
});



$('.ctn-food').cycle({

    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    timeout: 0,
    prev:".prev",
    next:".next",
    speed: 300,

    containerResize: 0,
    slideResize: 0,
    fit: 1,

});


$('.ctn-table').cycle({

    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 0,
    prev:".prev",
    next:".next",
    speed: 500,


    containerResize:0,
    slideResize: 0,
    fit:1


});
```